# Настройка Git на своем сервере

Tags: git

У меня установлен `debian`. Захотелось настроить свой репозиторий, например `git.site.com` (такая папка есть на сервере), и чтобы я мог, создавая в этой папке подпапки, создавать разные репозитории.
Прочитал много документации, установил `git` на сервере, выучил основные команды, но так и не понял, как правильно раздавать доступы, клонировать и заливать. Очень бы хотелось, чтобы, создав подпапку, например, `new_site`, я смог бы в ней создать репозиторий, и он бы был доступен по адресу `git.site.com/new_site` + доступы.
Кто-то может помочь с этим? A то уже голову себе сломал.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего для таких целей поставить гит сервер, например [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com). Там и управление репозиториями, и права доступа, и веб интерфейс для просмотра.

Другой вариант это создание репозиториев без `Gitlab`. Для этого вам нужно:

1. Установить `Git`
2. Создать юзера `git` с домашней директорией например `/home/git/`
3. Создать директорию для репозитория, например `/home/git/new_rep.git`
4. Перейти в новую директорию и инициаоизировать репозиторий `git init --bare`
5. Склонировать репозиторий к себе по ссылке `git@site.com:~/new_rep.git`

При этом доступ осуществляется глобально через системного юзера `git` для которого либо пароль задать можно, либо `id-rsa` ключ. Вообще в [документации](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) все доступно написано и даже на [русском](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5)

Comment: попробовал поставить GitLab. вроде вышло. только вопрос: как его запустить? я изменил адрес, порт который он должен слушать - эффекта 0. кто то знает, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: сразу хочу добавить, что на сервере крутятся сайты, поэтому порт 80, который я так понял идет по умолчанию, я использовать не могу

Comment: @Diefair запускается 'sudo gitlab-ctl start', если стоит nginx, то проксирование поддомена например не составит труда. Для решения проблемы лучше задать вопрос наверно на  http://serverfault.com

Comment: запустить я запустил, но что такое "проксирование поддомена" не знаю, если можно - подробнее